# Add props component into props parameter from reduxform callback

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I was wondering if this scenario can be somehow possible:

```
const MyComponent = ({props1, props2}) => (
  <div >
    // SOME STUFF using props1 and props2
  </div>
);


const ReduxFormWithMyComponent = reduxForm({
  form: 'test',
  onSubmitFail: (errors, dispatch, submitError, props) => {
    // here I would like to have access to props1 and props2 like:
    // const { props1, props2 } = props;
  },
  onSubmitSuccess: (result, dispatch, props) => {
    // same here:
    // const { props1, props2 } = props;
  },
})(MyComponent);
```

So basibally, I need to do some conditionnal stuff based on value from `props1` & `props2` in `onSubmitFail` and `onSubmitSuccess` callback.

According [documentation](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-onsubmitsuccess-function-code-optional-), I didn't see any details to do so.

Thank you

Comment: Your code is correct. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is inside the onSubmitFail (or onSubmitSuccess) body, I'm unable to get access to props1 (or props2)

Comment: the code there is correct so maybe you are not passing the props to ReduxFormWithMyComponent. please share the way you pass props and export this module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem which works. Might be useful for people having same issue.

Here is it:

Your component have to be like this shape:

```
const MyComponent = ({handleSubmit, props1, props2}) => (
  <div >
  <form
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => myCustomSubmitFonction(data, {props1, props2}))}
  >
    // SOME STUFF using props1 and props2
  </form>
  </div>
);
```

According [reduxform documentation](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-onsubmit-function-code-optional-), you can pass as props `handleSubmit` from reduxform. As a result, you can give in parameters to `handleSubmit` function whatever you want (In my case: `props1` and `props2`)

**Then**, `myCustomSubmitFonction` needs to return it:

```
myCustomSubmitFonction(reduxFormData, myCustomData) {
    // reduxFormData useless in my case
    return myCustomData;
}
```

**Now**, I can access to `props1` and `props2` via `result` (first parameter):

```
const ReduxFormWithMyComponent = reduxForm({
  form: 'test',
  onSubmitFail: (errors, dispatch, submitError, props) => {
    const { props1, props2 } = result;
    // Yay !!
  },
  onSubmitSuccess: (result, dispatch, props) => {
    const { props1, props2 } = result;
    // Yay !!
  },
})(MyComponent);
```